# Mirror modifier causing strange artifacts

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When I bring the edges together on a mirror modifier (clipping on) it does this weird thing when rendered as seen in the picture. I am not entirely sure how to describe it but it has happened before because I am bad at 3D modeling weapons. Anyways if you know how to fix please tell me sorry for the lack of information.

-Zek[image]

Comment: There is no picture... and the title doesn't really help... could you add more information so we know what your problem is?

Comment: Please use a proper title for your question.